# Java App to listen the printer queue and reroute jobs

Tags: java, printqueue

i want to write an app to listen to the jobs in the printer queue.

depending on the doc name (or some content in the doc) i want to
reroute this job to the correct printer. all printers are identical,
so formating will not be an problem.

my "printspoller" might be an additional installed printer, same type.

i apreciate any help on this
hannes

im able to count the jobs in queue via "queued-job-count"
but could not find to get the props of the docs.

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.util.Properties;  
import javax.print.attribute.Attribute;  
import javax.print.attribute.AttributeSet;  
  
import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.InputStream;  
import java.io.InputStreamReader;  
import java.lang.reflect.Array;  

import javax.print.DocFlavor;  
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;  
import javax.print.PrintException;  
import javax.print.PrintService;  
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;  
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;  
  
import java.text.DateFormat;  
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Date;  
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.Calendar;  
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;  

public class App {  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
        //GET ALL PRINTER NAMES
        System.out.println("Printers------------------");
    
        PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);  
        for (PrintService avPrt : printServices) {  
            
            System.out.println("\n\nPrinter installed: " + avPrt.getName());   
            AttributeSet attributesPr = avPrt.getAttributes();  
            for (Attribute a : attributesPr.toArray()) {  
                String name = a.getName();  
                String value = attributesPr.get(a.getClass()).toString();  
                System.out.println("     " + name + ": " + value);  
                //is it the queue?  
                if (name.equals("queued-job-count")) {  
                    Object queue = Integer.parseInt(value);  
                    System.out.println("          jobs in queue   : " + queue);
                }   
            }  
        }    
    }   
}  

//my spooler printer
//-----------------------------
Printer installed:SpoolerPrinter
     printer-info: SpoolerPrinter
     pdl-override-supported: not-attempted
     color-supported: not-supported
     queued-job-count: 5
          jobs in queue   : 5                   // i want to know the jobs with the doc name
     printer-name: Sewoo_POS_PRINTER
     printer-is-accepting-jobs: accepting-jobs


//my destination printers
//i want
Printer installed: InvoicePrinter
     printer-info: InvoicePrinter
     pdl-override-supported: not-attempted
     color-supported: not-supported
     queued-job-count: 0
          jobs in queue   : 0                   
     printer-name: Sewoo_POS_PRINTER
     printer-is-accepting-jobs: accepting-jobs


Printer installed: DeliveryNotePrinter
     printer-info: DeliveryNotePrinter
     pdl-override-supported: not-attempted
     color-supported: not-supported
     queued-job-count: 0                
          jobs in queue   : 5
     printer-name: InvoicePrinter
     printer-is-accepting-jobs: accepting-jobs
```

Comment: We are going to need some code to help you out with. This site is not meant to make us build complete solution for a question you ask, but to help improve code and helping out fixing bugs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.